# Set a specific bit to a specific value

Tags: c++, bitwise

This is the code I came up with:

```
void set_bit_at_pos(int* num, int pos, bool val)
{
    if (val) {
        int mask = 1 << pos;
        *num |= mask;
    }
    else {
        int mask = ~(1 << pos);
        *num &= mask;
    }
}
```

I'm new to bitwise operations, so this approach may not be the best. Nevertheless any suggestions are appreciated.

For the following main:

```
int main()
{
    int num = 5;
    cout << num << endl;
    set_bit_at_pos(&num, 1, true);
    cout << num << endl;
}
```

(I know about `using namespace std;`)

This is the output:

```
5
7
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you demonstrated how this function was expected to be used. In most cases I would recommend using unsigned int rather than int for num. There aren't very many reasons to adjust bits in signed integers and removing a bit may make it go negative.

Comment: Well, that's the point, @pacmaninbw , I'm not sure if it works correctly. I don't know if there's an off by 1 error, maybe bits start from 0 as well, and not from 1 which is I believe the way I wrote it. I'll provide some output though.

Comment: @MarkCeitlin Bitwise operations on `signed` integers are unsafe. If you want to manipulate bits on signed integers, it's better to cast to `unsigned` integers, manipulate, and cast back to signed integers

Comment: You should'nt ask a question if you're not sure your code works. At least you could have written some tests to verify the correctness of your method. Here's a great post about bit operations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit

Comment: I have retagged the question. This is clearly c++ code not c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simpler:

```
#include <stdint.h> // #include <cstdint> in C++

void write_bit_32b(uint32_t *num, uint8_t pos, bool val)
{

        *num &= ~(UINT32_C(1) << pos);
        *num |= (uint32_t)val << pos;
}
```

---

Use fixed-width integers if you can (see above).

---

Use `int main(void)`:

C17::6.11.6:

> Function declarators The use of function declarators with empty
>   parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an
>   obsolescent feature.

---

This may be interesting to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/6872717

Comment: The OP obviously asks about c++ code. Thus citing c standards is pretty useless here.

Comment: There is a subtle difference between `int main()` and `int main(void)` in C. In C++ though the use of `(void)` is equivalent to `()` it is considered archaic and to avoid confusion with `C` considered bad practice by most coding standards. There are only two valid declarations for main `int main()` and `int main(int, char**)` See: `n4820 6.8.3.1 main function [basic.start.main]`

Comment: @MartinYork In C, in a function definition, `()` and `(void)` are the same (unlike in function declarators other that definitions; don't remember and can't find the paragraph). Given that in C++ they are absolutely equivalent, although the wording of the standard is unfortunate, I would interpret it as in C17::5.1.2.2.1: *"or equivalent"*

Comment: BTW, the only reason for the `(void)` comment is that this question was originally asked as a C question, not C++

Comment: In `C` `()` and `(void)` are subtly different in that `void` indicates an unknown number of parameters. I was unaware that declaration and definition have different rules for `void` in `C`. But that just reinforces my conviction that you should use the version without `void` for both consistency and readability. Also since the rules are obscure using the one with the least exceptions would be best from a maintenance stand point.

Comment: @MartinYork In C, that would be `void`, which always means zero parameters, and is the only non-deprecated standard way. It is `()` that indicates an unknown number of parameters in some cases, and is explicitly an obsolescent feature in the standard.